# lsusb not showing flash drive

Tags: usb, usb-drive, lsusb

I have a USB flash drive that previously worked with my main PC running Ubuntu 18.04. A couple of days ago the flash drive is no longer visible in the Ubuntu OS. However, the flash drive still works perfectly on other computers, including another PC running Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows.

My main PC can still recognise other USB flash drives, just not that specific drive that I use (it is a mSATA drive boxed up with a usb connector).

I've tried:

1. lsusb, lsblk - no signs of the device visible on my main PC at all
2. Tried different USB cables and different USB ports on on the same PC.
3. Rebooting the computer

Any idea why is this happening? Is it just that my PC and that particular USB drive hate each other?

Comment: Would GParted "see" it? Stupid question - does it have a "I  am on " LED?Assuming  your OS does not detect it  just by plugging it in / hot swap?

Comment: If Ubuntu is installed and runs on the PC, you could try the output of `dmesg | tail` to see if there are any USB related errors.

Comment: @JanHus Neither GParted or Disks see it. The Flash drive's LED turns on and it warms up when it's plugged in.

Comment: @mikewhatever `dmesg | tail` doesn't seem to give any output hinting the presence of usb drives.

Comment: Test by booting the computer (where you cannot 'see' the USB drive) **live** from another USB drive, for example a USB pendrive, with Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. If it can see the drive that way, we know that the problem is with the installed operating system. Otherwise we don't know what is the problem, but if it can be seen by other computers when booted from the same USB pendrive, we can suspect that some hardware has been changed somehow, maybe some kind of degradation or failure.

Comment: Unplug the drive. In a terminal, type `journalctl --follow`. Plug in the drive.

Comment: If you setup is UEFI / EFI instead of BIOS verify your USB options.
( It has  USB to SATA adapter / interface right ?)